# How to prevent submit depend on result of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC Project, i want button to not make submit if the result come from AJAX code is false.

But the it always make submit.

That is the code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <input name="CategoryID" id="myCategoryId" type="text" value="0" />

    <input name="CategoryName" id="myCategoryNameId" type="text" value="" />


    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="myid" type="submit" value="Add" />
}
```

and that is Javascript code:

```
$('#myid').on('click', function(event) {

    var data = {};
    data.CategoryName = $("#myCategoryNameId").val();
    data.CategoryID = $("#myCategoryId").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: '/Category/ValidateCategoryName',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            if (!result) {

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You could try on form submit instead of button click

Comment: $.ajax is an asynchronous call, the form is submitted long time before the success function is called. change the button type from `submit` to `button` and submit the form in the success function.

Comment: Come to think of it, you could also consider forcing $.ajax  to be synchronous by specifying  async: false

Comment: What do you expect result to contain ? You specify it should be json but you are handling it like a boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd replace the submit button input element with a button element so that clicking the button will trigger the onclick event without submitting the form. Then when you get the ajax response you can conditionally use jQuery to submit the form. This might require some tinkering to get the form from the onclick but it'll prevent you from submitting the form too early like I suspect your problem is.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input name="CategoryID" id="myCategoryId" type="text" value="0" />
    <input name="CategoryName" id="myCategoryNameId" type="text" value="" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Add</button>
}
```

and

```
$('#myid').on('click', function(event) {
    var data = {
        CategoryName: $("#myCategoryNameId").val(),
        CategoryID: $("#myCategoryId").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: '/Category/ValidateCategoryName',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $('#myid').closest('form').submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I copied and pasted from another answer for that part. Although it's not functionally a mistake, I do agree it is a bad coding practice so I'll fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Ohh, it work fine, that is exactly what i want because this code use the id of the button, i only need to change the type of input to button instead of submit, thank you man

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment above. change

```
  <input class="btn btn-primary" id="myid" type="submit" value="Add" />
```

to

```
  <input class="btn btn-primary" id="myid" type="button" value="Add" />
```

And in your success function, change

```
if (!result) {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

to

```
if (result) {
   $('#myid').closest("form").submit();
}
```

This way you will only submit the form when result is true, it the ajax call fails or result is false then the form won't be submitted.

DISCLAIMER: The code above may not work, but i hope you get the generel idea.

Answer (score 1):

What I know from a very long time is the `Form` default redirect action will not wait until ajax returned its result .. So you can use a boolean variable to control that .. see the next code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var DefaultFormAction = false;   //set the default form action to false
  $('form').on('submit' , function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(DefaultFormAction == false){  // when the default action is false 
      e.preventDefault();   // prevent the default redirect
      setTimeout(function(){   // I use setTimeout here for testing .. Use the next code in your ajax success
        DefaultFormAction = true;   // return default action to true
        $this.submit();       // then submit the form again
      } ,10000);
      console.log('This result when default is false you will go to the default form action after 10second');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="CategoryID" id="myCategoryId" type="text" value="0" />
  <input name="CategoryName" id="myCategoryNameId" type="text" value="" />
  <input class="btn btn-primary" id="myid" type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

To test **the `Form` default redirect action will not wait until ajax returned its result** you can use `e.preventDefault()` inside the `setTimeout` and even you make a time is `1`ms without `$this.submit()` it will still use the default redirect

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var DefaultFormAction = false;   //set the default form action to false
  $('form').on('submit' , function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(DefaultFormAction == false){  // when the default action is false 
      setTimeout(function(){   // I use setTimeout here for testing .. Use the next code in your ajax success
        e.preventDefault();   // prevent the default redirect
      } , 1);
      console.log('This result when default is false you will go to the default form action after 10second');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="CategoryID" id="myCategoryId" type="text" value="0" />
  <input name="CategoryName" id="myCategoryNameId" type="text" value="" />
  <input class="btn btn-primary" id="myid" type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohammed, it work right, but i have many form in the page, so i want to use the id of the form instead, but not work when use the id, what can i do ?  $('form-id').on('submit', function (e) { ... }

Comment: @mustafa id in selector starts with `#` ya mustafa .. `$('#form-id')` .. But ou must know that the id should be unique .. this means don't use the same id with more than one element .. if so the code will work with just the first one . to use selector with multiple elements use `class`es instead of `id`s

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way to do so:

```
$(document).on('submit','form' function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $this = $(this);

    var data = {};
    data.CategoryName = $("#myCategoryNameId").val();
    data.CategoryID = $("#myCategoryId").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: '/Category/ValidateCategoryName',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $this.submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it nothing happen, but the code of @Mohammed work right

Comment: Can you share with me with team viewer. I would like to see the behavior!